# What is dual Equivalent table in hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Suppose we want to run the following query in oracle

```
select sin(0) from dual
```

What would be the corresponding query in hibernate?
(using "dual" in hibernate is the highlight of the question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Hibernate equivalent of "select 1 from DUAL"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844798/what-is-the-hibernate-equivalent-of-select-1-from-dual) In addition, some options worth to investigate: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944201

Comment: Why would you want to run such a statement? The sinus can be calculated much more efficiently in Java directly. Or is `sin(0)` just a simplified example hiding your _real_ problem?

Comment: considering your answer, do you have any suggestion that I can deal with "from TABLE" while I want to have the answer from no table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as you guessed , it is just a simplification of a much more complicated one.